# Laravel 5 (custom) method for calculating age(in days) does not exist

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

there's a lot of similar questions but I did not find the solution for my problem, so here's the issue:

I have a simple function that should be used for calculating age (in days), listed in the SubmissionController:

```
public function agingDate($sub) {
  $to = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $sub);
  $now = Carbon::now();
  $diff_in_days->age = $to->diffInDays($now);

  return $diff_in_days;
}
```

Also, in the same controller:

```
public function index() {
  $submission = Submission::orderBy('location_address_state', 'asc')
                                ->get();
  return view('/subs/index', [
        'submission' => $submission
  ]);

}
```

And finally, in my view, I'm trying to call this function:

```
 @if($submission)
   @foreach($submission as $sub)
     <p>{{ $sub->created_at->agingDate() }}</p>
   @endforeach
 @endif
```

The message I'm receiving is "Method agingDate does not exist. (View: /subs/index"). Why can't I access this function - it's in the same controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep the separation of concerns intact, I would suggest that you move your `agingDate()` method into your `submission` model.

So, in your `Submission` model, you could refactor it in the following way:

```
public function agingDate() {
  $to = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->created_at);
  $now = Carbon::now();
  return $to->diffInDays($now);
}
```

In your blade file, you should then be able to call:

```
@if($submission)
   @foreach($submission as $sub)
     <p>{{ $sub->agingDate() }}</p>
   @endforeach
 @endif
```

The approach you are currently using doesn't work, since you are trying to call the aging method on a plain property of your Submission instance.

Comment: This was originally in my Model but since it didn't work, I just tried different things and ended up with having this function in my Controller. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.